# Non-Nullable Virtual Propery in Entity Framework Code-First Model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, non-nullable

I need to generate two database tables with a one-to-many relationship from my site's Entity Framework models; Blog and Tag. A blog can have many tags but a tag can only belong to one blog.

My Blog model consists of an ID property (Guid) as a primary key and a Name property (string). Similarity my Tag model consists of an ID property (int) as a primary key and a Name property (string). The Tag model also has a virtual property Blog which should generate a foreign key to the Blog table's ID column.

Below is an extract from my model classes:

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

When the database is created using code-first, the Blog_ID column in the Tag table allows a null or a random GUID to be inserted. How do I enforce it to never allow nulls or a value other than an existing and valid Blog ID using a code-first approach?

Comment: Where is `Site_ID` ?

Comment: Apologies, typo - was meant to say Blog_ID. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the [RequiredAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your porperty.

```
[Required]
public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class should be declared similar to the below code.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
suing System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

public class Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid BlogId { get; set; };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add this field to your Tag class:

```
[Required]
public Guid BlogId { get; set; }
```